# Tensorflow Create Dataset from csv and mapping

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, dataset

I try to create a Dataset for Tensorflow from a CSV file that I created with pandas.

The csv file looks like this:

```
feature1     feature2     filepath     label
    0.25         0.35    test1.jpg         A
    0.33         0.15    test2.jpg         B
```

I read the dataframe like this

```
mydf = pd.read_csv("TraingDatafinal.csv",header=0)
```

Now I have defined a function which should return a dataframe. This is all according to [the quickstart guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/datasets_quickstart)

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    """An input function for training"""
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

    # Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(mappingfunction)
    # Return the dataset
    return dataset
```

I call this function like this;

```
mydataset = train_input_fn(mydf.drop(["label"],axis=1),mydf["label"],200)
```

This works, if I remove the mapping but I get a questionmark when I print the shape. Why? The dimensions seem to be clearly defined.

This is where the real struggle begins. I want to create a mapping function, that replaces the filepath with an array of the image.

I tried to achieve that by writing this mappingfunction

```
def mappingfunction(feature,label):
    print(feature['Filename'])
    image = tf.read_file(feature['Filename'])
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image)
    return image,label
```

This will only return the image and the label. I don't know how I would realize it to return all the features but the filepath.

But even this simplified verison won't work. I get an "expected binary or unicode string" error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping function should return all features and the label. For example:

```
def mappingfunction(feature,label):
    print(feature['Filename'])
    image = tf.read_file(feature['Filename'])
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image)
    features['image'] = image
    return features, label
```

This will add an `image` key to the features dictionary.